# Springboot 2.1.7.RELEASE REST API returns 406 on WAS Liberty version 18.0.0.8 (wlp-javaee8-18.0.0.4)

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty

I am deploying a springboot 2.1.7 application as war on wlp-javaee8-18.0.0.4 and getting 406 httpstatus when calling my rest endpoint from postman

My service:

```
@PostMapping(path = "/authentication/schema", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> hello(@RequestHeader("key") String key) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("X-KEY", schemaPair.getValue());
    headers.SetContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    return new ResponseEntity<>("hello", headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

From postman i specify ContentType and Accept headers as follows :
 - Content-Type: application/json
 - Accept: application/json

I have tried also:
 - Content-Type: */*
 - Accept: */*

Debugging springboot show that the problems commes from java servlet. To be precise, it is here :

```
package org.springframework.http.server;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

public class ServletServerHttpResponse implements ServerHttpResponse {

    private final HttpServletResponse servletResponse;

    // after code

    @Override
    @Nullable
    public String getFirst(String headerName) {
        String value = servletResponse.getHeader(headerName); // problem here
        /*
        * this method servletResponse.getHeader(headerName) 
        * returns text/html while my contenttype is application/json
        */
        if (value != null) {
            return value;
        }
        else {
            return super.getFirst(headerName);
        }
    }

    // after code
}
```

Any idea please

Thnaks a lot

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a filter that overrides my contentType in websphere liberty servlet. I removed the filter and things went ok

On tomcat my filter works

I do not know if this is a bug or not !